# <vaadin-horizontal-layout> is vertical, not horizontal

Tags: vaadin

I have a question about Vaadin components. I've successfully added them to static web pages using their declarative APIs (HTML APIs). (See https://web-call.cc/ .) The HTML API for element  (https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-ordered-layout/html-examples) shows usage like this:

```
<vaadin-horizontal-layout>
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
</vaadin-horizontal-layout>
```

but I have to add the style `display: flex;` to make the layout horizontal. Why must I do that? (I got the idea from viewing the layout with Dev Tools in Chrome, which showed the horizontal layout with that style.) When I added that style rule for both the horizontal layout and the vertical layout, the vertical layout went horizontal, too! The documentation doesn't show that style being applied to the layouts; only to the items contained in those layouts. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The reason the layouts were misbehaving is that I forgot these imports:

````
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-vertical-layout.js'
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/vaadin-horizontal-layout.js'```
````

Comment: I was just about to write that also as an answer when I saw that this was posted. Please note that you're also missing the import for the `<vaadin-list-box>` element on the same page.